# Is it possible to run a java script in a partial view in MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I've read some posts saying that you cannot have sections in partial views and that they simple don't work. I'm experiencing this myself, after many hours of struggling. However, I also have seen some posts showing some solutions, although none of them using the razor engine. My question is: Is there anyway to execute scripts in partial view MVC 5 razor? If not, any work around? What I'm doing now is to put the script in the section of the view that (will) contain the partial view. It is working well so far, although I would prefer to have each page with its own scripts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you really don't want to put script into your partial since they will be inserted into the middle of your page.  Put the script for your partial into your main page or a referenced script file.  To tie the script to your partial tie it to the document

```
$(document).on('click', '.partialButton', function(){
    //script here
});
```

the button on your partial will now trigger this click event.  Let me know if you have any questions.